Aligning separate datasets with different CRS in QGIS for the purposes of terrain modelling
I would like to develop a 3D model of a site located in Vermont, USA. I will be using the state's LiDAR dataset which I am pretty comfortable with. However, I need to coordinate this topographical model with a separate field survey and 3D models of existing buildings on site (done by others). The surveyor has provided me with a series of control points (LAT. and LONG.) which I am hoping to use to align the output out of QGIS into these other files on separate programs.
I am not sure how to project the survey points into the CRS of my QGIS file currently set to the State's own CRS. I am using a .csv import to bring these points into my file.  Can someone refer me to the right direction to get an answer?

Please post a link to your data. What steps have you tried so far?

You are going to need to confirm the vertical datum of LiDAR data which will be spelled out in the LiDAR report (most likely NAVD88).  You are going to need to confirm the vertical datums of both the surveyor data and any existing 3D data you may receive.  These data will all need to share both a vertical datum and a horizontal datum.
Lucky for you your data are in the USA so any vertical datum conversion can happen in vDatum.  vDatum will do the horizonal conversions as well including lat/longs to Vermont State Plane.  The link provided has information on installing vDatum, using vDatum online, as well as a tutorial on vertical datum conversions.
